# FPDF insert text

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I have a html form which sends the answers onto a pdf document. Everything is working fine but I would like the questions to be on the pdf document as well.

currently it looks like this on the pdf:

```
Jurgen
Yes
No
4
No
```

I would like it to be:

```
Name: Jurgen
Do you own a vehicle? Yes
etc
```

(SOLVED)
my current code for the fpdf file:

```
<?php

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('images/logo.png', 10, 6, 30);

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);

    $this->Cell(50);


    $this->Cell(90, 10, 'Document Title', 'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
 }

 // Page footer
 function Footer()
 {

    $this->SetY(-15);

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);

    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
 }
 }
?>
<?php
//set the question values
$questions = array(
           'name' => "Name: ",
           'date' => "Date: ",
           'first' => "First Day of Leave: ",
           'last' => "Last Day of Leave: ",
           'days' => "Number of Days Taken: ",
           'email' => "Managers Email: ",
           'sig' => "Signed: ",

         );
//set the question answers
$date = $_POST['date'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sig = $_POST['sig'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
//set the question names
$questionName = $questions['name'];
$questionDate = $questions['date'];
$questionFirst = $questions['first'];
$questionLast = $questions['last'];
$questionDays = $questions['days'];
$questionEmail = $questions['email'];
$questionSig = $questions['sig'];
//Create the PDF

require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
//insert questions and answers
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionDate, $date));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionName, $name));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionFirst, $first));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionLast, $last));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionDays, $days));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionEmail, $email));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionSig, $sig));
//display pdf
$pdf->Output();
```

I am still learning about FPDF since their documentation isn't the best. If I have made some mistakes please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Post your full html form so I can give you a proper answer, I've used fpdf a lot

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have sorted this issue out thanx to AnthonyB. Thank you sir but I am having trouble setting a page header. If you could give me an example for it?

Comment: by page header you mean the header on your pdf file?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes sir i have tried adding the header with class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Header()
{ but it doesnt work, I have edited my code above so it shows all my code.

Comment: I will edit my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you can have your question in an associative array where the key matches with `name` attribute in your html form.

form.html

```
<form action="your_post.php" method="POST">
    <!-- Your first question about age -->
    <label>
        What's your name?
        <input name="name" type="text" />
    </label>
    <!-- Your second question -->
    <label>
        How old are you ?
        <input name="yo" type="text" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

your_post.php

```
<?php
$questions = array(
               'name' => "What's your name?",
               'yo' => 'How old are you?'
             );
//Get you question and answer about name
$name = $_POST['name'];
$questionName = $questions['name'];
//You can of course use a foreach through $_POST to get every question

require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
//Here concatenate $questionName and $name
$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,sprintf("%s %s", $questionName, $name));
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: How would i code this on my html form sir? currently have it as Name: <input type=text name="name">

Comment: Thank you sir im all set ^^

Answer (score 0):

i can't help you with that explicit question, but i had to write a script a few days ago, which also creates a pdf.
I found a very nice tool to do this, which i decided to use instead of fpdf. It directly converts html code to a pdf. (you can also link css into it) maybe this can be also interesting for you.
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf

Comment: Indeed html2pdf is a great tool to convert directly a html view to PDF. It's an easy way to do it. But here he's trying to create the PDF himself, and the problem about question stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
<?php
$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Name : ' . $name . '');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->cell(20, 10, 'Do you own a vehicle? : ' . $question1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**adding header, the problem you facing now**

```
<?php

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('images/logo.png', 10, 6, 30);

        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);

        $this->Cell(50);


        $this->Cell(90, 10, 'Document Title', 'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {

        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);

        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
}
?>
```

Update this is how your final code should look

```
<?php
//set the question values
$questions     = array(
    'name' => "Name: ",
    'date' => "Date: ",
    'first' => "First Day of Leave: ",
    'last' => "Last Day of Leave: ",
    'days' => "Number of Days Taken: ",
    'email' => "Managers Email: ",
    'sig' => "Signed: "

);
//set the question answers
$date          = $_POST['date'];
$first         = $_POST['first'];
$last          = $_POST['last'];
$days          = $_POST['days'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];
$sig           = $_POST['sig'];
$name          = $_POST['name'];
//set the question names
$questionName  = $questions['name'];
$questionDate  = $questions['date'];
$questionFirst = $questions['first'];
$questionLast  = $questions['last'];
$questionDays  = $questions['days'];
$questionEmail = $questions['email'];
$questionSig   = $questions['sig'];
//Create the PDF

require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('images/logo.png', 10, 6, 30);

        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);

        $this->Cell(50);


        $this->Cell(90, 10, 'Document Title', 'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {

        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);

        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
}


$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
//insert questions and answers
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionDate, $date));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionName, $name));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionFirst, $first));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionLast, $last));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionDays, $days));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionEmail, $email));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionSig, $sig));
//display pdf
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: answer updated @J.Hof you getting that error because you using the class before you include it in your script. now your script should work

Comment: Ok sir no errors now. But there is no header or footer showing on my pdf

Comment: what do you wanna display on the hedader?

Comment: Leave Application Form

Comment: `class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        //$this->Image('images/logo.png', 10, 6, 30);

        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);

        $this->Cell(50);


        $this->Cell(90, 10, ' 
Leave Application Form', 'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }`